# Prevent/protect div from .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making simple HTML list with sub div, and I made javascript code with jQuery that opens and closes `div` under `li` element, but I don't want to have `div` closed after clicking on that `div`. Let me make simple.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".submenu-cat ").click(function( event ){
   
   var activeClass = $( this ).hasClass( "active" );
   if(activeClass == true){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
   }
   
   $(this).children('.sub-open').slideToggle();
   
  });
});
```

```css
.tabler .active {
 background: #f79925;
 color:white;
 border-bottom:0;
}
.tabler .active h3 {
 color: white ;
}
.submenu-cat {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.submenu-cat .sub-open {
 display:none;
 background: #eeeded;
}
.tabler {
 padding-left: 10px;
}
.tabler li {
 list-style:none;

}
.tabler .boxined .right_actions {
 float:right;
 
 color:white;
 margin-top:10px;
 opacity:0.8;
}
.tabler .boxined .right_actions div {
 text-align:centeR;
 border-right:solid 1px white;
 float:left;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size:12px;
}
.tabler .boxined .right_actions div a {
 color:white;
}
.tabler .boxined {
 border-top:solid 1px lightgrey;
 border-bottom:solid 1px lightgrey;
 height:66px !important;
}
.tabler li .image {
 float:left;
 margin-right: 20px
}
.tabler li:hover {
 background:#f79925;
 color:white;
}
.tabler li:hover h3 {
 color:white;
}
.tabler h3 {
 font-size:17px;
 font-weight:600;
 margin-left:15px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabler ">
 <li class="submenu-cat">
  <div class="boxined">
   <a href="#">
    <div class="image">
     <img src="img/pic1.png" width="64" height="64" />
    </div>
    <h3>my list #1</h3>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-open">
   Description
  </div>
 </li>
<ul>
```

If you run snippet, you'll see that you can close the `sub-open` div by clicking on it. I don't want that. How can I somehow, prevent that `sub-open` div from `click()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following, i have added a click handler to `.sub-open` in this is stop the propagation, now if this is reached then it is finish, no other handler would be called.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".submenu-cat ").click(function( event ){
   
   var activeClass = $( this ).hasClass( "active" );
   if(activeClass == true){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
   }
   
   $(this).children('.sub-open').slideToggle();
   
  });

        $('.sub-open').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
});
```

```css
.tabler .active {
 background: #f79925;
 color:white;
 border-bottom:0;
}
.tabler .active h3 {
 color: white ;
}
.submenu-cat {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.submenu-cat .sub-open {
 display:none;
 background: #eeeded;
}
.tabler {
 padding-left: 10px;
}
.tabler li {
 list-style:none;

}
.tabler .boxined .right_actions {
 float:right;
 
 color:white;
 margin-top:10px;
 opacity:0.8;
}
.tabler .boxined .right_actions div {
 text-align:centeR;
 border-right:solid 1px white;
 float:left;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size:12px;
}
.tabler .boxined .right_actions div a {
 color:white;
}
.tabler .boxined {
 border-top:solid 1px lightgrey;
 border-bottom:solid 1px lightgrey;
 height:66px !important;
}
.tabler li .image {
 float:left;
 margin-right: 20px
}
.tabler li:hover {
 background:#f79925;
 color:white;
}
.tabler li:hover h3 {
 color:white;
}
.tabler h3 {
 font-size:17px;
 font-weight:600;
 margin-left:15px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabler ">
 <li class="submenu-cat">
  <div class="boxined">
   <a href="#">
    <div class="image">
     <img src="img/pic1.png" width="64" height="64" />
    </div>
    <h3>my list #1</h3>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-open">
   Description
  </div>
 </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to check which element the user has clicked

```
$(".submenu-cat").click(function( event ){
    var $target = $( event.target );
    if($target.hasClass('sub-open')){//user clicked the div

        return;
    }
    var activeClass = $( this ).hasClass( "active" );
    if(activeClass == true){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    $(this).children('.sub-open').slideToggle();
});
```